# What is the thread group leader name in the /proc file system?

Tags: linux-kernel, procfs

Is the name of the thread group leader available in `/proc`? I am looking for the `group_leader->comm field` for a given `task_struct`.

Comment: The `/proc` directory seems to be structured like `/proc/$TGID/task/$PID/`, where `$TGID` is the thread group ID (the PID) and `$PID` is the thread ID (TID). (The differences in terminology between userspace and kernelspace are confusing!). Also the `/proc/$TGID/task/$PID/status` file will list "Tgid" (the thread group ID, i.e. the process PID, which I showed as $TGID above), "Ngid" (the Numa group ID), "Pid" (the thread ID, i.e. the TID, which I showed as $PID above), "Ppid" (the parent process ID), and other stuff. The name of the thread group leader will be shown in `/proc/$TGID/comm`.

Comment: `/proc/$TGID/comm` is name of the thread itself and not the name of the group_leader. This is how its showing up on my Centos7. Are you sure you're seeing the group_leader name?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. All PIDs including TIDs show up under `/proc/$PID`. The `/proc/$PID/status` file will list the threag group leader as "Tgid: $TGID" and then you you can read `/proc/$TGID/comm` to get the name of the thread group leader.

Comment: "show up" in procfs is misleading: a directory read will return only process-related entries (with a PID number). In contrast path traversal also resolves TIDs.